# Using a string variable with multiple words in a foreach command

Tags: stata

I have a string variable “education”, which takes on the values “no college”, “college degree” and “some college”. I have written the following `foreach` command:

```
foreach i in no college some college college degree {

Egen medianwealth_`i'=median(wealth) if education= "`i'"

}
```

However, Stata does not recognise “no college” as a single expression, and instead treats “no” and “college” as distinct. Thus it sees “college” twice and gives an error message reading “medianwealth_college already exists”. Quotation marks have not helped. How do I get Stata to recognise each expressions as distinct?

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues with your loop as is:

1. Even with quotations, your strings have spaces so will not be a valid suffix in `` medianwealth_`i' ``.
2. Your `if education=` needs `==` to test equality. A single equality is used for assignment.
3. `Egen` needs to be lower case.

**Data Example**

```
clear
set seed 10
input str20 education 
"no college" 
"some college" 
"college degree"
end
expand 3 
gen wealth = runiform(20000,100000)
sort education wealth

list

     +----------------------------+
     |      education      wealth |
     |----------------------------|
  1. | college degree   41338.556 |
  2. | college degree   45074.926 |
  3. | college degree   92455.948 |
  4. |     no college   22885.894 |
  5. |     no college   68102.649 |
     |----------------------------|
  6. |     no college   68589.262 |
  7. |   some college   56733.812 |
  8. |   some college   80254.404 |
  9. |   some college   93096.349 |
     +----------------------------+
```

**Fixing original loop**

```
foreach i in "no college" "some college" "college degree" {
    local suf = strtoname("`i'") // make valid variable name
    egen medianwealth_`suf' = median(wealth) if education == "`i'"
}
```

**Improving loop**

You can make your code more robust by using `levelsof` to capture the distinct values of your variables.

```
levelsof education, local(educations)
foreach i of local educations {
    local suf = strtoname("`i'")
    egen medianwealth_`suf'_2 = median(wealth) if education == "`i'"
}
```

If you want your values in a single variable, you can simply use one `egen` expression:

```
egen median_wealth = median(wealth), by(education)
```

```
     +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     |      education      wealth   medianwealth_no_college   medianwealth_some_college   medianwealth_college_degree   medianwealth_college_degree_2   medianwealth_no_college_2   medianwealth_some_college_2   median_wealth |
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. | college degree   41338.556                         .                           .                     45074.926                       45074.926                           .                             .       45074.926 |
  2. | college degree   45074.926                         .                           .                     45074.926                       45074.926                           .                             .       45074.926 |
  3. | college degree   92455.948                         .                           .                     45074.926                       45074.926                           .                             .       45074.926 |
  4. |     no college   22885.894                 68102.649                           .                             .                               .                   68102.649                             .       68102.649 |
  5. |     no college   68102.649                 68102.649                           .                             .                               .                   68102.649                             .       68102.649 |
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  6. |     no college   68589.262                 68102.649                           .                             .                               .                   68102.649                             .       68102.649 |
  7. |   some college   56733.812                         .                   80254.404                             .                               .                           .                     80254.404       80254.404 |
  8. |   some college   80254.404                         .                   80254.404                             .                               .                           .                     80254.404       80254.404 |
  9. |   some college   93096.349                         .                   80254.404                             .                               .                           .                     80254.404       80254.404 |
     +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And if your intention was to have each variable be entirely populated by the group medians, you could do something like this:

```
levelsof education, local(educations)
foreach i of local educations {
    local suf = strtoname("`i'")
    qui sum wealth if education == "`i'", detail
    gen medianwealth_`suf'_3 = r(p50)
}
list  education wealth *_3, abbreviate(32)

     +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     |      education      wealth   medianwealth_college_degree_3   medianwealth_no_college_3   medianwealth_some_college_3 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. | college degree   41338.556                       45074.926                   68102.649                     80254.404 |
  2. | college degree   45074.926                       45074.926                   68102.649                     80254.404 |
  3. | college degree   92455.948                       45074.926                   68102.649                     80254.404 |
  4. |     no college   22885.894                       45074.926                   68102.649                     80254.404 |
  5. |     no college   68102.649                       45074.926                   68102.649                     80254.404 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  6. |     no college   68589.262                       45074.926                   68102.649                     80254.404 |
  7. |   some college   56733.812                       45074.926                   68102.649                     80254.404 |
  8. |   some college   80254.404                       45074.926                   68102.649                     80254.404 |
  9. |   some college   93096.349                       45074.926                   68102.649                     80254.404 |
     +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```